# Golang crypto: encrypted file not prefixed with IV

Tags: go, cryptography, aes

I am using an IV in cipher.NewOFB, but my encrypted file never gets prefixed with it. I followed the golang examples at https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/cipher/, but can't seem to figure out why the prefix isn't being considered.

Does anyone see what the problem is?

```
func generateRandomIV(length int) []byte {
    iv := make([]byte, aes.BlockSize)

    if _, err := io.ReadFull(rand.Reader, iv); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    return iv
}


func encryptFile(filename, keystring string) error {
    readFile, err := os.Open(filename)
    iv := generateRandomIV(aes.BlockSize)

    outFile, err := os.OpenFile(filename+".enc", os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE|os.O_TRUNC, 0600)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    defer readFile.Close()
    defer outFile.Close()

    key := []byte(keystring)

    block, err := aes.NewCipher(key)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("IV:", iv)
    writer := &cipher.StreamWriter{S: cipher.NewOFB(block, iv), W: outFile}

    if _, err := io.Copy(writer, readFile); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the IV prefix yourself or pre-share the IV. If you prefix it you will have the remove it and apply it on decryption.

How an IV is shared is not part of the encryption standard, it is a developer choice. Prefixing the IV is common but not required or the only way, it is however a good choice.

Comment: Are you saying I should add the bytes to the file myself? Why does NewOFB take IV as a parameter if it doesn't do anything with it?

Comment: Yes, that is usually what is done when you are using encryption at this low level.

Comment: Note, is keystring is a human readable string it should not be used directly as a key, instead the encryption key should be derived from it with a derivation function such as PBKDF2. That will mea even more data needs to be bundled with the encrypted data: the salt and iteration count.

Comment: Thanks zaph, I'll give it a shot!

Comment: One more point, when using a stream cipher (OFB) the IV and key combination can never be reused, in this case  `rand.Reader` is a cryptographically secure random number generator so you should be safe.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense now: IV is passed to cipher.NewOFB because the encryption method will use it during the encryption process. The actually IV is not stored in the file, this must be done manually.

Comment: By prefixing the encrypted data the IV does not need to be saved anywhere, it will be available for decryption, this is common practice. The IV is not secret and should be a random bytes.